# How to divide a line or a curve into n equal pieces and tick it using PSTricks

Tags: pstricks

When we draw `\psaxes` they initially have ticks and there's an option which lets us to omit them. I'm trying to put some ticks on my `\pscurve`, I was wondering is there a way to divide a line or a curve into n (e.g., 12) equal pieces and put a tick for them? As we do for the axes.

```
\documentclass{article}

‎\usepackage{pstricks‎ , ‎pst-plot}‎
‎\usepackage{pst-bezier}‎ 
‎\usepackage{pst-math}‎

\begin{document}

‎\psset{xunit=0.5cm,yunit=0.5cm}‎‎‎
‎\centering‎
‎\begin{pspicture}(8,8)‎
‎\psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(8,8)[$x$,0][$y$,0]‎‎
‎\pscurve{-}(1,1)(3,4)(6,6)(8,4)‎‎% want to devide this curve into 6 equal pieces and putting a tick on each
‎\end{pspicture}‎‎

\end{document}
```

this is what I get

[image]

While I want to have something like this :

[image]

Comment: Sample code please! Give the wizards something to work with.

Comment: I added to code

Comment: calculating distance along a parametric curve requires calculus, so the answer to your question is going to be dependent on the curve and whether you can differentiate the expressions symbolically or numerically (and is likely to be hard either way:-).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: we have PostScript and the `flattenpath` function. The reason why we do _not_ need something to calculate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the current versions of `pstricks.tex` and `pstricks.pro` you can do something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=0.5cm}
\begin{pspicture}(9,8)
\psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(8,8)[$x$,0][$y$,0]
\pscurve(1,1)(3,4)(6,6)(8,4)
\pscurve[linestyle=symbol,symbolStep=11.6pt,% must be positive 
  curveticks,startAngle=60](1,1)(3,4)(6,6)(8,4)
\end{pspicture}
\begin{pspicture}(8,8)
\psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(8,8)[$x$,0][$y$,0]
\pscurve[linestyle=symbol,symbolStep=-12,% must be negative !
  curveticks,startAngle=60](1,1)(3,4)(6,6)(8,4)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The left image has the ticks placed with a fixed width and the right one with a calculated width given by the number of ticks. The first tick is placed by the value of `startAngle` because we cannot calculate the slope for the first point.

For more informations read the file `pst-news12.pdf` all available in the next few days with the TeXLive update manager or already at `http://texnik.dante.de`

Instead of plotting a curve by coordinates one can also plot a function:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=0.5cm}
\begin{pspicture}(0,-4)(15,5)
\psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(0,-4)(14.5,4.5)[$x$,0][$y$,0]
\psplot[algebraic,plotstyle=curve,linestyle=symbol,
  curveticks,symbolStep=8pt]{0}{14}{ 1.75*(sin(x)+2*cos(x)^2) }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are those shapes (dot,triangle,etc) all we can have as symbols or is there a way to change the dots ticks ?

Comment: as I wrote, read the doc: run `texdoc pst-news10`

Comment: I'll upload a solution with tick marks on the curve at afternoon

Comment: @Negin: I updated my answer.

Comment: I am interested to know whether it is very hard in TikZ.